# Use a database according to host in single .war

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee, mybatis

I have a single war (webapp.war) which can be accessed from subdomain1.mydomain.com and subdomain2.mydomain.com.

I want to use different databases according to the domain, like when i access subdomain1.mydomain.com i want to use "database1" and when i access subdomain2.mydomain.com i want to use "database2".

I've already configured the hosts in tomcat server.xml:

```
<Host name="subdomain1.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
   prefix="subdomain1_access_log" suffix=".txt"
   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Context path="" docBase="C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/webapp"
    debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>

<Host name="subdomain2.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
   prefix="subdomain2_access_log" suffix=".txt"
   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Context path="" docBase="C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/webapp"
    debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

Btw, i am using iBatis and Spring MVC.

Is there anyway i can achieve this using a context or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the hostname using this annotation as a parameter to controllers:

```
@RequestHeader String host
```

What I would do is to create a wrapper that would set the appropriate datasource depending on the hostname.

Define 2 datasources, 2 sqlSessionFactory and 2 MapperFactoryBean (one for each domain):

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryDomain1" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryDomain2" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapperDomain1" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.your.mapper.interface" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactoryDomain1" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapperDomain2" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.your.mapper.interface" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactoryDomain2" />
</bean>
```

Then create a service that you'll use for accessing your database. The service will use either mapperDomain1 or mapperDomain2 based on the host value.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how i can do it using the wrapper?